# Bluetooth settings not clickable, how do I set it up?

Tags: 11.10, bluetooth

I am  not able to enable disable bluetooth from system settings 
buttons are not clickable.

I am not able to connect to bluetooth please help.

Comment: Did you try connecting the bluetooth device first and then running `sudo service bluetooth restart`

Comment: Great this worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this alternative way

Get your bluetooth device MAC or BT ADD or BlueTooth Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

In a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez
```

libbluetooth3 will also be installed.

```
sudo apt-get install python-gobject python-dbus
sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Press the reset or pair button on your keyboard, simple-agent will ask to specify a pin like 1111, then type that pin on the bt keyboard and your bt keyboard is paired.

```
sudo bluez-test-device trusted XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX yes
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

Now your device should be working. Check:

```
dmesg|tail
```

The last messages should be about the paired keyboard (and mouse in my case)